# Eclipse PDE - how to find method usages

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I've just started developing my first plugin so apologies if this is obvious.

I'm trying to write a plugin that gets method usages and does something with them.

I've seen references to `CallHierarchy` and `SearchEngine`. Which is the correct one to use these days and why, when I use "Open Type", can it not be found? Is there a dependency I'm missing or something?

Comment: _...when I use "Open Type", can it not be found..._ See https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_a_particular_class_from_an_Eclipse_plug-in%3F

Answer (score 0):

These classes are part of the Eclipse JDT plugins and are not normally included in the search done by Open Type.

To get 'Open Type' to look everywhere for the classes open the Preferences and go to the 'Plug-in Development' page. Select the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option.

You will also need to install the Eclipse SDK to get the source of these plug-ins. The SDK is part of the Eclipse update site `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7` for Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: and for finding methods, which is the correct/preferred way?

Comment: I am not an expert on the use of these classes.

Comment: @TedTrippin The results of _Call Hierarchy_ and _Java Search_ are presented differently to the user. [Java Search allows wildcards](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-java-search.htm) and is therefore perhaps the preferred way in your case.

Comment: I'm currently using `SearchEngine` to search for `*`, `DECLARATIONS` and `METHOD`. seems to be working :)